# how to change the s-function data using command line

Tags: matlab, command-line, s-function

can anyone tell me how to change the s-function parameters using the command line.

i used the following lines to get the s-function data:

```
blkNames = find_system(system,'lookundermasks','all','BlockType','S-Function');
blkHandle = get_param(char(blkNames), 'Handle');
appdata = sfunctionwizard(blkHandle,'GetApplicationData');
```

next i try to change the number of outports and inports by accessing the appdata structure. but how do i write back this appdata structure back to the s-function. is it possible? or is there any other way i can achieve the s-function's data/parameters/inports manipulation

Comment: Did you find any solutions to the problem? Thanks

Comment: @giga no i could not find any solution. and in the end i had to use a template to generate the s-function code manually